# pythonpath for google app engine in pydev eclipse

Tags: python, google-app-engine, path

I have  `google app engine` installed to /home/mydev folder such that dev_appserver.py is in `/home/mydev/google_appengine` directory.

In eclipse helios,I have pydev and for my project's PYTHONPATH,I added the path `/home/mydev/google_appengine/lib` under external libraries.

Still,pydev compains it cannot resolve

```
import webapp2
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inside PyDev, have you created your project as a google app engine project (that's a project type that PyDev has)... The wizard to create that kind of project should automatically get the google app libraries so that your import works.

See: http://pydev.blogspot.com.br/2009/05/testing-on-pydev-146-google-app-engine.html

Answer (score 1):

I am using Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2, PyDev 2.2.3, and GAE 1.6.5 and I get the same problem by pointing external libraries to `/home/mydev/google_appengine/lib` (or the equivalent on my machine), but it resolves when I point the external libraries to `/home/mydev/google_appengine`, the parent directory.

Hope this helps (this is an empirical solution that worked for me and have no specific reason why it works).

Comment: thanks for the reply..I tried that..but it doesn't solve the problem..Anyway thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

You need to add /home/mydev/google_appengine/lib/webapp2 in PYTHONPATH. Because within this directory only webapp2 module resides.